# CSS and XPath selectors in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, casperjs, selectors-api

this function works very well, (this gives all `<div class = "menuFamille" ..>` for each `<div class = "menuRayonContent avecLiens" ..>` )

```
function getnb1() {
  var num1 = document.querySelectorAll(".menuRayonContent.avecLiens .menuFamille");// I get all divs menuFamille each div with class as "menuRayonContent avecLiens"
  return Array.prototype.map.call(num1, function (e) {
     try {
         return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1]
     } catch (err) {
         return e.getAttribute("href");
     }
  });
}
```

But there div whose class is simply "menuRayonContent" so the result gives 0 and I don't know how to find all divs with class as with or without "avecLiens"

and I will proceed as it

```
function getnb2() {
  var num1 = document.querySelectorAll (".menuRayonContent .menuFamille"); // I get all //divs menuFamille each div with class as "menuRayonContent"
  return Array.prototype.map.call(num1, function (e) {
      try {
         return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1]
      } catch (err) {
         return e.getAttribute("href");
      }
  });
}
```

This account all `<div class = "menuFamille" ..>` in the page.

and as the page is like this

```
<div class = "menuRayonContent avecLiens" style = "display: block;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1025" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1026" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "290" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2595" typecat = "2">
  ..........
  ...........
<div class = "menuRayonContent " style = "display: none;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "4024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1325" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1226" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2590" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1595" typecat = "2">
.............
.............
<div class = "menuRayonContent " style = "display: none;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "4024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1325" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1226" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2590" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1595" typecat = "2">

...........
...........
```

Or like this

```
<div class = "menuRayonContent avecLiens" style = "display: none;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1025" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1026" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "290" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2595" typecat = "2">
..........
...........
<div class = "menuRayonContent " style = "display: block;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "4024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1325" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1226" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2590" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1595" typecat = "2">
.............
.............
<div class = "menuRayonContent " style = "display: none;">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "4024" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1325" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1226" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "2590" typecat = "2">
<div class = "menuFamille" idCat = "1595" typecat = "2">
...........
...........
```

I think of counting  divs with class attributes = "menuRayonContent" or class = "menuRayonContent avecLiens" and style = "display: block;" but until now I can't, (I use casperjs)

this is my function:

```
function getnb() {
  var links = __utils__.getElementsByXPath(x('//div[contains(class, "menuRayonContent" && style = "display: block;")]'));
  return Array.prototype.map.call (links, function (e) {
     return e.getAttribute('href');
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript. What are `e.getAttribute return ('href');`, `__ __ getElementsByXPath utils (x (...`?

Comment: can you help me in my problem please!!!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your second code block should solve your issue. If not please describe the problem you're having a little better.

Comment: yeah, I think that style = "display: block;" is my issue to resolve my problem,

Comment: that's what I want to do but I don't know how

Comment: I reexplain my problem

Comment: getnb1 function worked with success but I also want have the number of <div class="menuFamille" > of <div class = "menuRayonContent "

Comment: I want select this style = "display: block;" but I don't know, what must I do

Comment: There are still some problems. 1. Your XPath syntax is wrong. You probably mean `//div[contains(class, "menuRayonContent") and contains(style, "display: block;")]`. You have to split the predicates. 2. Your example `.menuFamille` are not `a` elements. They don't have a `href` attribute. You probably want to select `.menuFamille a`.

Comment: Thank you Artom B. for answering me

Comment: I would count the divs <div class = menuFamille idCat = "xxx"> present in a div <div class = "menuRayonContent" style = "display: block;"> or in a div <div class = "menuRayonContent" style = "display: none; "> or in a div <div class =" menuRayonContent avecLiens "style =" display: none; "> or in a div <div class =" menuRayonContent avecLiens "style =" display: block; "> for I can use the xpath to click on it. The xpath of these dependent on .menuFamille's numbers in each .menuRayonContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that all the typos are gone, to reiterate you want to select all `.menuFamille` elements under `.menuRayonContent` which are visible and you want them separate. This mean that you have to iterate over the container and then iterate over the children.

The clientutils module of CasperJS has an undocumented function `{boolean} elementVisible({DOM element} elem)`. You can use this to iterate over all visible `.menuRayonContent` and then build a list with their children.

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".menuRayonContent");
container = Array.prototype.map.call(container, function (c) {
    var obj = {
        number: 0,
        children: null,
        visible: __utils__.elementVisible(c),
        className: c.getAttribute("class")
    };
    var children = c.querySelectorAll(".menuFamille");
    children = Array.prototype.map.call(children, function (child) {
        return child.getAttribute("idCat"); // or something else that you need
    });
    obj.number = children.length;
    obj.children = children;
    return obj;
});
```

For your example DOM this should yield:

```js
container = [
    {
        number: 5,
        children: [
            "1024", "1025", "1026", "290", "2595"
        ],
        visible: true,
        className: "menuRayonContent avecLiens"
    },
    {
        number: 5,
        children: [
            "4024", "1325", "1226", "2590", "1595"
        ],
        visible: true,
        className: "menuRayonContent"
    }
];
```

You can of course remove filter out invisible `.menuRayonContent` elements using

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".menuRayonContent[style*='display'][style*='block']");
```

The `[attr*='value']` matches all elements whose `attr` attribute contains `value` somewhere.

Comment: Hi! I have a new subject, how to parse a piece of code in a file? please. thank you.

Comment: I don't know. I you have a question, just [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).